# Wamp PhpMyAdmin visual bug

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I've had this issue before but have not quite figured out how to solve it, it effects all browsers.

When I start up Wamp and go to PhpMyAdmin -> databases to create a new test database my view looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/33ciog

as you can see it seems to cut off part of it and so i cant access the options to create a new db.

What causes this and how can i fix it?

Comment: with which user are you logging in into phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i typed admin but the moment i read your comment i went to go check something and logged in with root, which seems to have fixed it. out of curiosity though, why does that occur?

Comment: As phpMyAdmin says - you didn't have permissions to create a DB and probably the guys don't see this view to often so they didn't realise the way in which it's displayed

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the quick informative reply. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default account setup by a MySQL install is:-

```
Username = root
Password = ( leave this blank) there is no password set initially
```

root is what is called the SUPER USER, and has access to do anything.

Once you are logged in with an actual MySQL account you can then create other accounts with varying accesses and privileges

It is actually documented in the MySQL manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html